# Fatal error: Class 'Codeception\Platform\Extension' not found. Issue occurred after magento 2.3.0 upgrade to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-community, unit-tests, phpstorm

**Preconditions (*)**

1. 1.Magento 2.3.1 upgraded from Magento 2.3.0
2. Php 7.2.15
3. OS : Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
4. Phpstorm 2019.1.1
5. Evnironemnt : Magento development

**Steps to reproduce (*)**

1. Issue appears after upgrading magento from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 and run below commands.
2. bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
3. vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist.
4. Above commands will work if version 2.3.0 is installed directly and also for 2.3.1 if installed directly.

These commands should run unit test on entire magento project not just on one mdoule.

**Error (*)**

> `Fatal error: Class 'Codeception\Platform\Extension' not found in`
>   `/var/www/html/magento23demo/vendor/allure-framework/allure-codeception/src/Yandex/Allure/Adapter/AllureAdapter.php`
>   `on line 49`

Please note I can't find Platform\Extension codeception library in vendor folder.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059726/phpstorm-v2017-3-4-codeception-v2-4-0-incompatibility

Comment: @magefms Lookslike its Codeception Framework library issue with magento 2.3 not a phpstorm compatibility issue at this point since I ran the unit test from console and got the same message. `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist`

Comment: I see, found another one which I think a slightly related to your issue https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser/issues/42

Comment: I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BackGround:**
Problem occurred after using the cli upgrade method method mentioned [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html). First enable the maintenance mode so that website becomes inaccessible.

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

For upgrade following command was used

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.1 --no-update
```

This command will only update the composer.json file "require" key. Because of --no-update flag it will not install the new magento version along with new packages.
This can be verified from composer.lock file which contains the list of all currently installed packages. Search for magento/product-community-edition in composer.lock file it will still how the version to be 2.3.0.

Now if you run below unit test command it will work fine as magento is still 2.3.0 version.

```
bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

Moving on above error(Class 'Codecception\Platform\Extension' not found) is related to allure-framework package in vendor directory.

- allure-framework package gets installed as dependency of magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework package **(Abbr: mftf)**.
- It has two folders Alulure-Codeception and Allure-php-api.
- **Observe the Adapter/AllureAdapter.php file**. This will change after update.

  With magento version 2.3.0, mftf version 2.3.9 gets installed as can be noted in "require-dev" key of composer.json file.

[image]

Now run

```
composer update
```

This will update your magento installation and you will see numerous packages gets updates. Few but not all updates are shown in snap below. Total updated 173 and 11 new installs. Also your composer.lock file will be updated as well.

[image]

Again run and you will see that the error mentioned in this question will appear.

```
bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

**Solution:**

Remove your current package magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework package which is version 2.3.9 as follows

```
composer remove magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework
```

You will notice this command will remove numerous packages along with following packages shown in pictures below

[image] 
[image]

> NOTE: If you dont run composer update in previous steps and try to
>   remove mftf following error will happen
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.3.0, required as 2.3.1) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Problem 2
>
> - Can only install one of: amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[3.1.4, 3.0.0].
> - Can only install one of: amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[3.1.4, 3.0.0].
> - Can only install one of: amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[3.0.0, 3.1.4].
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module 3.1.4 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[3.1.4].
> - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].
> - Installation request for amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module (locked at 3.0.0) -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[3.0.0].

Now since allure-framework and mftf 2.3.9 has been removed we can install latest mftf version suitable for magento version 2.3.1 as follows.

```
composer require magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.13 --dev
```

Notice it will install latest version of allure-framework and mftf along with many other packages. Snap below

[image]

Now notice that allure-framework with allure-codeception and allure-php-api folders.

- **Observe that Adapter/AllureAdapter.php has changed to Codeception/AllureCodeception.php after new mftf version 2.3.13 installation**.

Now again run

```
bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

You will see that a new error(below) will appear which means previous error (Class 'Codeception\Platform\Extension' not found) is resolved.

> Class "Yandex\Allure\Adapter\AllureAdapter" does not exist

It can be resolved as follows

A vanilla installation of magento 2.3.1 was done and it was observed that a new folder allure-phpunit is added into allure-framework as given in picture below

[image]

Hence install allure-phpunit into your **upgraded** magento 2.3.1 as follows

```
composer require allure-framework/allure-phpunit --dev
```

This will give following error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for allure-framework/allure-phpunit ^1.3 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.3.0].
> - allure-framework/allure-phpunit 1.3.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >=7.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.1.5, 7.2.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 7.2.5, 7.2.6, 7.2.7, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 7.3.4, 7.3.5, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3, 7.5.4, 7.5.5, 7.5.6, 7.5.7, 7.5.8, 7.5.9, 7.5.x-dev, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4, 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 8.1.3, 8.1.x-dev, dev-master, 8.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

phpunit/phpunit version is 6.5.0 in composer.json both in upgraded magento 2.3.1 and in vanilla installed 2.3.1. Hence allure-framework/allure-phpunit version 1.3 which is latest version will not be installed as it required phpunit/phpunit >=7.0.0.

So install

```
composer require allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 --dev
```

It will install latest 1.2 version of phpunit/phpunit compatible to upgraded magento 2.3.1 installation.

Now run again

```
bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

SUCCESS !! phpunit test will start running for the entire project with following command line output. A snippet is given below
[image]

Comment: For Magento 2.3.3 I had to specifically use version 1.2.3 of allure-phpunit as 1.2.4 uses the PHPUnit 7+ version of setUp() (setUp(): void) while the Magento tests still appear to use PHPUnit 6 way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

```
composer require magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:"2.3.13" allure-framework/allure-codeception:"1.3.0" allure-framework/allure-phpunit:"1.2.3" --dev
```

This is the smallest composer update to make unit tests work for M2.3.1 community edition. If you (for some reason like me) want composer.lock to have minimal changes and minimal affection on other packages.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is a missing dependency.

Running `composer install` should resolve the issue.

It's working for me.

Comment: Hi @Saphal Jha. It didn't work for me. Which magento and php version are you using and which command did use for the test.

Comment: I am using from git directly and I am running d:t:r

Comment: That explains it I faced issue after an upgrade

Comment: Also i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If anyone come across a similar error after upgrade, it's most likely due to `AlluerAdapter` class does not exist anymore and your `phpunit.xml` is listening to the wrong class. However, verify the `alluer-framework` package exists. Then you could just simply update your `phpunit.xml` listeners to `Yandex\Allure\PhpUnit\AllurePhpUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.7-p3

```
composer require magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.6 allure-framework/allure-codeception:"~1.4" allure-framework/allure-phpunit:"~1.2" --dev
```