# Error: Class "Yandex\Allure\Adapter\AllureAdapter" does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, testing, phpunit, mftf

Preconditions (*)

1. Magento 2.3.1 upgraded from Magento 2.3.0
2. Php 7.2.15
3. OS : Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
4. Phpstorm 2019.1.1
5. Evnironemnt : Magento development

Steps to reproduce (*)

- Issue appears after upgrading magento from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1.
- Removing magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework
- installing latest magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.13
- Running below commands.

> bin/magento dev:tests:run unit

OR

> vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist

These commands should run unit test on entire magento project not just on one mdoule.

NOPTE: Above commands will work if version 2.3.0 is installed directly and also for 2.3.1 if installed directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install following package as follows since 2.3.0 didn't came with allure-phpunit.

This issue is related with following issue

> [Fatal error: Class 'Codeception\Platform\Extension' not found. Issue occurred after magento 2.3.0 upgrade to 2.3.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270555/fatal-error-class-codeception-platform-extension-not-found-issue-occurred-af)

So in order for upgraded 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 magento to work install following.

```
composer require allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 --dev
```

Then run

```
bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

Comment: How come it doesn't come with Magento out of the box?

Comment: While doing unit tests this was the error I was getting. I have updated the header. From investigation it appeared that magento 2.3.1 upgraded from 2.3.0 created compatibility issues for the allure-framework versions. Clean 2.3.1 comes with different allure-framework and upgraded 2.3.1 stays on the older version which has a different implementation.

Comment: Ah right interesting.. during the Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 upgrade, did you diff composer.json files and bring over the new changes?

Comment: No I didn't I just followed the cli procedure recommended by magento for upgrades. [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html]

Comment: Option --dev is default. It's not necessary to specify it. From documentation:

`--dev:` Install packages listed in require-dev (this is the `default behavior`).